# file mime type validation if file is uploaded in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload, mime

I have a file upload field as :

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
```

This field is optional. User may add file or not.

I want file type validation and I don't want to allow user to add files other than images. This is I have done so far.

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'image.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,tiff |max:4096',
    ],$messages = [
        'mimes' => 'Please insert image only',
    ]);
```

But, when there is no file is uploaded, validation doesn't got passed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Make a work arround, if file not empty $val = 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,tiff |max:4096'; else '' and put the $val into 'image.*' => $val,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**As per Laravel 5.8**

For file validation using request data for `required`, `mime type` & `file size` check before uploading file:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,tiff |max:4096',
    ],$messages = [
        'mimes' => 'Please insert image only',
        'max'   => 'Image should be less than 4 MB'
    ]);

dd($validator->errors());
```

**Note:** Don't forget to use Validator Facade

Answer (score 0):

I would probably check if the file is present in the request and then run the validation for it.
Eg:

```
if ($request->has('image') {
    // Do your validation check
 }
```